# Moving an image up and down continuously in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a react website and in it I have an image the I want to be continuously moving up and down at a certain rate (like on [this site](http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/#/)) to signal to the user that it's a button that scrolls the page down. I can't seem to find a good way of doing this so I was wondering what a good way to accomplish this is?

Comment: Open the dev tools. Find the element with the class name `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down`. Have a look at the css, it's using an animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be css animations.

For instance:

```
.moveArrow {
  animation-name : mymove;
  animation-iteration-count : infinite;
  animation-direction : alternate;
  animation-duration : 2s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {transform: translateY(0px);}
  to {transform: translateY(20px};}
}
```

Mymove is a css animation, and then if you gave your arrow the class .moveArrow, it would have the animation applied to it, running an infinite number of times in alternating directions.